# Will this type of filtering work in a belongs_to association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For a recruitment application, I have a user model, which has many common_app.

Each user will actually only have 1 common_app, but in case in the future they have more, I'm setting it up as a has_many association.

In the common app, I'm thinking of having the following data ->

```
user_id:integer
current_city:string
grad_year:integer
read_type:string
listen_speak:string
time_in_china:integer
desired_industry:(not sure, will be a multi-select picklist)
location_pref:(not sure, will be a multi-select picklist)
```

---

What I'm confused with doing this though, is that a part of the functionality of the app is to filter users based on their answers.

With this type of association, will I be able to filter all users, based on their answers? i.e all users whos grad_year is 2005 ?

If yes, how would I write the command to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :apps
end

class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

User.includes(:apps).where('apps.grad_year = 2005')
```

Comment: awesome! Thanks ceny. As general advice, do you think this is the best way to do it? Or would you opt for a different type of association?

Comment: i update my post, start from User may looks more natural. The model design is based on your description. I need more info like requirement or use cases to decide whether is the best way.